# Do linear functions have a slant asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the function $y=mx+b$ has a slant asymptote $y=mx+b$?

Or it doesn't have asymptotes?

What is the convention?

Comment: You will need to state the definition of "asymptote" to be used.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "slant asymptote"...

Comment: Many authors use the notion of [an asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) in the context of a function or the graph of a function to mean a straight line whose distance to the curve approaches zero but does not become identically zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any curve $f(x)$ is trivially asymptotic to itself. The more interesting case is when it's assumptotic to a *simpler* function. Conventionally, unless specified otherwise, we limit asymptotes to *linear* functions.

In your case, if $m\neq 0$ and $m\neq \infty$ then it has a trivial *oblique* asymptote $mx+b$. If $m = 0$ it has a horizontal asymptote $y=b$ and if $m=\infty$ then it has vertical asymptote $x=0$

The wikipedia article on this is actually pretty good:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote